# Skip and Take option for java arraylist?

Tags: java, linq, arraylist

I am very new to java, i know skip and take are very easy using linq in dot net. But i dont know how to achieve skip and take process in java for array list. any linq like option available in java?

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you can take advantage of [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at [this link](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/03/29/c.net-little-wonders-skip-and-take.aspx) to understand what are "skip and take".

From Java 8, you can do such things with Streams. `Stream.filter()` enables you to define a `Predicate` which is your equivalent of `take()`. You can obtain `skip` by filtering on the opposite `Predicate` :

```
List<Integer> list = [...];

List<Integer> result = list.stream()
    .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0) //Use any Predicate you want.
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); //Convert the Stream back to a list
```

Answer (score 8):

Arnaud Denoyelle is correct; you want to use streams.

The Java 8 equivalents of .NET's `.skip()` and `.take()` are [`.skip()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) and [`.limit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-)